# Lazy load a module from lazy load route

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have done lazy load route and shared module which can import first in main module and available in lazy module.

But I want to load shared module when lazy module required that module, For example in my main module I have a login route only and this page don't required any kind of library. So I don't want to import that library first time, library should import when I go to another route.

When we have only login screen with core functionality it have very small bundle size, but with lots of library it increase size. I want to main module should be a small bundle.

How can I achieve this.

Comment: Use of chunks will solve your problems

Comment: Angular provide create chunk of lazy route module. All shared module which can use in multiple route and we want to import once, it include in vendor bundle

Comment: divide your shared module into several parts and import only in which it is required .

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

[Lazy loading: code splitting NgModules with Webpack](https://toddmotto.com/lazy-loading-angular-code-splitting-webpack)

"Let’s talk about code splitting in Angular, lazy-loading and a sprinkle of Webpack. Code splitting allows us to essentially break our codebase down into smaller chunks and serve those chunks on demand, which we call “lazy loading”. So, let’s learn how to do it and some of the concepts/terminology behind it."

Comment: This sample is about lazy load module from routing. Shared module still import in main module that mean libraries imports in vendor bundle and no benefit of code splitting.. I wan't to import lazy load module outside of routing.